# using fetch to post and get data rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, model, get, fetch

am trying to post and get data from my model from and to the view using fetch. am able to get a specific item with an id say 'boats/1' but not all the boats from '/boats'.

heres my code, i have canceled the JSON parse, because it gives an error since they is no JSON
 [heres my code, i have canceled the JSON parse, because it gives an error since they is no jason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAlH5.jpg)

```
   fetch('/boats')
//   .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((messages) => {console.log(messages);});

fetch('/boats/3')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((messages) => {console.log(messages);});


  fetch('/jobs')
    // .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((messages) => {console.log(messages);});

fetch('/jobs/1')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((messages) => {console.log(messages);});
```

Here is my output, the first is for fetch #2, the next two are for fetch # 1 and 2, i get a response but not what i want, i want an array with all the items in the models, last is for the last fetch, here i did not cancel out the JSON parse
[Here is my output, the first is for fetch #2, the next two are for fetch # 1 and 2, i get a response but not what i want, i want an array with all the items in the models, last is for the last fetch, here i did not cancel out the JSON parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pptp.jpg)

{id: 3, name: "boat2", cargo: 102, location: "NY", created_at: "2018-09-25T00:40:33.653Z", …}

Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/boats", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/jobs", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

GET http://localhost:3000/jobs/1 500 (Internal Server Error)

edit:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

​

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If possible, you'll get better help if you edit the question to include the relevant code, rather than linking to images. There's a good guide to writing questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As is, it's a little hard to help - with a little tweaking I'm sure you'll get the answer you're after though :)

Answer (score 0):

the issue may not be in the fetch call, but rather in how you are handling that query at the controller. Also double check that you have your routes pointing to the right controller#action